# Find the probability that exactly $12$ customers arrive from $9$A.M to $11$ A.M

Tags: probability, solution-verification, poisson-distribution

Customer arrivals at a payment counter in a with an average of nine per hour

Assume that the number of customer arrivals at a counter in each hour behaves independently. Find the probability that exactly $12$ customers arrive from $9$A.M to $11$ A.M

Parameter $\lambda=9$ per hour so there $2$ hours between  $9$A.M to $11$ A.M therefore $\lambda=18$

$P(X=12)=\dfrac{e^{-18} 18^{12}}{12!}$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.  For a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ per unit of time, the random number of events per $t$ units of time is a Poisson random variable $X(t)$ with rate $\lambda t$, with probability mass function $$\Pr[X(t) = x] = e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^x}{x!}, \quad x \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}.$$  In your case, $\lambda = 9$, your units of time is $1$-hour increments, and $t = 2$ hour increments.  Thus the probability that there are $12$ arrivals during a $2$-hour increment is $\Pr[X(2) = 12]$, which is what you wrote.

Comment: Thank you can you please tell me can I use gamma distibution for this problem?

Comment: @noname Using the gamma distribution answers a different question. You're currently asking for the probability that 12 customers arrive in 2 hours. If you were asking for the probability density in time for 12 customers to arrive, then you would use the gamma distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationships_among_probability_distributions#Sum_of_variables

Comment: @motherboard thank you